# IIS Windows Authentication on local machine

Tags: authentication, iis, active-directory

I would like to be able to run/debug locally. The machine is a laptop that is on a domain, however at times I do take it home. I have IIS installed as well as SQL Server. Everything is running correctly. I just have one issue, I must be on the domain so that the MVC site that configured to use Windows Authentication will run. I would like to figure out how I can remove this dependency on the domain controller. Specifically I would use local users when I am not connected to the domain, or only use local users in development testing.

Comment: Local users should authenticate, but If you don't describe what is the exact problem with local users it is impossible for others to help.

Comment: The issue is the development machine is on a domain, however I do not always have access to the domain, such as when I am traveling. I would like to 'tell' IIS to use local users for Authentication instead of looking for the DC, which it will not find.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web.config file for your website:

```
<add key="AuthorizedADGroup" value="Administrators"/>
```

Anyone in your local Administrators group will then be able to access the site through Windows Authentication.  Alternatively, you can also create a local group called say "Developers" or "Testers" or "Engineering", add local users to those groups, and sub one of those groups in for Administrators instead.

Comment: It looks like an AppSettings node however I would assume it is not... what are the parent nodes in the config file?